# Is my schema for a financial securities database correct?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm currently using a spreadsheet to calculate monetary allocations between financial products and regions. The table below is a small subset of thhe spreadsheet which has several hundred lines of data and more layers to the hierarchy:

```
+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+
| product_L1_id | Allocation | product_L2_id | Allocation | product_L3_id | Allocation |   region_id   | Allocation | country_id | Allocation | Net allocation |
+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+
| Bonds         | 100.0%     | Normal        | 60.0%      | Government    | 70.0%      | EMEA          | 80.0%      | UK         | 30.0%      | 10.1%          |
| Bonds         | 100.0%     | Normal        | 60.0%      | Government    | 70.0%      | EMEA          | 80.0%      | France     | 70.0%      | 23.5%          |
| Bonds         | 100.0%     | Normal        | 60.0%      | Government    | 70.0%      | North America | 20.0%      | US         | 0.0%       | 0.0%           |
| Bonds         | 100.0%     | Normal        | 60.0%      | Government    | 70.0%      | North America | 20.0%      | Canada     | 100.0%     | 8.4%           |
| Bonds         | 100.0%     | Normal        | 60.0%      | Corporate     | 30.0%      | EMEA          | 60.0%      | UK         | 80.0%      | 8.6%           |
| Bonds         | 100.0%     | Normal        | 60.0%      | Corporate     | 30.0%      | EMEA          | 60.0%      | France     | 20.0%      | 2.2%           |
| Bonds         | 100.0%     | Normal        | 60.0%      | Corporate     | 30.0%      | North America | 40.0%      | US         | 50.0%      | 3.6%           |
| Bonds         | 100.0%     | Normal        | 60.0%      | Corporate     | 30.0%      | North America | 40.0%      | Canada     | 50.0%      | 3.6%           |
| Bonds         | 100.0%     | Foreign       | 40.0%      | High yield    | 80.0%      | EMEA          | 30.0%      | UK         | 60.0%      | 5.8%           |
| Bonds         | 100.0%     | Foreign       | 40.0%      | High yield    | 80.0%      | EMEA          | 30.0%      | France     | 40.0%      | 3.8%           |
| Bonds         | 100.0%     | Foreign       | 40.0%      | High yield    | 80.0%      | North America | 70.0%      | US         | 30.0%      | 6.7%           |
| Bonds         | 100.0%     | Foreign       | 40.0%      | High yield    | 80.0%      | North America | 70.0%      | Canada     | 70.0%      | 15.7%          |
| Bonds         | 100.0%     | Foreign       | 40.0%      | Government    | 20.0%      | EMEA          | 100.0%     | UK         | 0.0%       | 0.0%           |
| Bonds         | 100.0%     | Foreign       | 40.0%      | Government    | 20.0%      | EMEA          | 100.0%     | France     | 100.0%     | 8.0%           |
| Bonds         | 100.0%     | Foreign       | 40.0%      | Government    | 20.0%      | North America | 0.0%       | US         | 70.0%      | 0.0%           |
| Bonds         | 100.0%     | Foreign       | 40.0%      | Government    | 20.0%      | North America | 0.0%       | Canada     | 30.0%      | 0.0%           |
+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------+
```

Worth me pointing out that the same `product_L3` can appear under a different `product_L2` - see "Government" as an example.

The key output of the spreadsheet is the `Net allocation` field which is the product of all the individual allocations.

I'd like to convert this into my first database and I'd like to check my thinking before I spend lots of time implementing it. It seems obvious to me that there's the opportunity to use multiple tables so is my first attempt at a schema(?):

- `product_L1` table with id and allocation columns
- `product_L2` table with id and allocation columns
- `product_L3` table with id and allocation columns
- `Region` table with id and allocation columns
- `Country` table with id and allocation columns

I was then planning on using a foreign key in each table to link it to the previous table in the hierarchy. However, taking the `Country` table as an example - I think this will need each country to be duplicated multiple times and each record will have to have foreign keys from all the previous tables in order for a query to work out the `Net allocation`. Is this right/efficient? Is there a different way of thinking about this? I've read about nested sets but am not sure if they'd be the best solution here?

This isn't going to be a database for multiple users - just me.

Comment: You wouldn't normally have 3 tables, each storing the same kind of thing.

Comment: Would you recommend using an adjacency or nested set model? I looked at this but they looked like I’d simply be reformatting my current spreadsheet into fewer columns but many more rows. How would you approach this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand the model's intent well enough to advise further - but dont get too hung up on it; just go with what feels right, and accept it that you'll have to revise the schema as you go.

Comment: Ok thanks. At this stage it really is as simple as getting the ```Net allocation``` figure.

Comment: And what are the `SELECTs`?

Comment: @Rick - not sure I understand the question?

Comment: @Jossy - One 'test' for a database schema design is to see if you can write the queries that will work that data.  (And you have to do that eventually.)

Answer (score 1):

Your database design looks fine to me.

- product_l1 (product_l1_id, allocation)
- product_l2 (product_l2_id, allocation)
- product_l3 (product_l3, allocation)
- region (region_id, allocation)
- country (country_id, allocation)

One could argue that a product is a product and one table with a product level indicator would suffice, but I consider this model with three tables appropriate. It guarantees that a level 1 product can not be used as a level 2 product for instance.

What's missing is the table holding the combinations you are showing:

- combinations (product_l1_id, product_l2_id, product_l3_id, region_id, country_id)

### UPDATE:

Looking at your data again, two things come to mind.

1. A country seems to belong to a region, so the country table should get a region_id.
2. A region has no fixed allocation.
3. In your sample data you are using the same combinations with different countries. You may hence want this split in two steps.

This would get something like this:

- product_l1 (product_l1_id, name, allocation)
- product_l2 (product_l2_id, name, allocation)
- product_l3 (product_l3, name, allocation)
- region (region_id, name)
- country (country_id, name, region_id, allocation)
- product_combination (product_combination_id, product_l1_id, product_l2_id, product_l3_id)
- region_combination (product_combination_id, region_id, allocation)
- final_combination (product_combination_id, country_id)

Comment: Thanks Thorsten - this is great. I'll build it as above and let you know how I get on - including the all important 'accept answer' :-)

Comment: Thanks. I've made one more update, as I just noticed that your region allocation is not fixed. This makes this a tad more complicated. (And if I am right with the tables now, I would even tend to have a composite key for the country table consisting of region_id plus country_id, so as to be able to guarantee consistency in the table hierarchy. The final table would then have a region_id, too, because that would be part then of the country table key.)

Comment: Quick Q - how does the above take account of L3 where "Government" appears twice with a different allocation?

Comment: It doesn't. Another thing I didn't see. Can the same happen to product 2 to? Can 'Normal'  have another allocation than 60%? It seems you need more sub-combination tables to get this completely normalized.

Comment: With p = product and r = region and c = country, it seems you'd get the tables p1, p2, p3, r, c, p1_p2, p1_p2_p3, p1_p2_p3_r, p1_p2_p3_r_c to store all allocations separately and you still could not guarantee that you would always end up with 100% per group. So maybe you just don't normalize this at all and just have p1, p2, p3, r, and c, for the IDs and names plus one spreadsheet table p1_p2_p3_r_c to hold all allocations. Sorry, I don't see the perfect database for this where all consistencies are guaranteed.

Comment: On Normal - no it couldn't have another allocation. Thanks for all your help on this. I've been reading more about Nested Sets and I think I'm going to go down that route as the hierarchy is pretty messy.